# Associating a custom preview URL with a .cfm file in ColdFusion Builder (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

In my usual ColdFusion directory layout all files are accessed via a controller called r.cfm that uses an include to pull in the actual .cfm file, so a file called "salaries.cfm" would be invoked via http://servername.com/r.cfm?name=salaries

In Eclipse with the ColdFusion extensions I could set the file properties so the default url for salaries.cfm would be http://localhost/r.cfm?name=salaries - when I ran the debugger that url would launch, not http://localhost/salaries.cfm - how do I set that up in the ColdFusion Bulder beta, the debug configuration is always non editable per file.

I have played around with server prefixes but that does not seem to do it.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible in CFBuilder -- as you said, this setting is not per-file. You could put in an Enhancement Request, though, if you wanted: https://bugbase.adobe.com